# Is NodeJS the only server behind React Native apps?

Tags: react-native, server

I read the React Native documentation and I've only seen nodeJs.
Are they other servers?

EDIT: when you deploooy your app on stores, what's the server behind your app?

Comment: React Native is for the most part a frontend framework. Anything frontend is agnostic to the server (you can use whatever you want as a server).

Comment: thanks so what's the point with node?

Comment: where did you read that? can you please share the links?

Comment: here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

React Native is a javascript framework which is used to develop mobile apps(frontend). For the backend of the app you can use any server you want because it doesn't matter to frontend what backend or server are you using. Node is used as a tool for bundler and downloading packages